# extracting value with xpath yields some unwanted strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I am extracting values from webpage (webscraping). I can succesfully get the line containing desired value, but, I was hoping for the value itself. Do I do it right and it really requires extra step of striping?

some methods from `lxml.html`

```
title = doc.xpath('//*[@class="tytng"]')
print (lh.tostring(title[0]))
```

webpage code:

```
<span class="tytng" style="">06MAGNA&nbsp;(06N)</span>
```

expected result:

```
06MAGNA&#160;(06N)
```

actual result:

```
b'<span class="tytng">06MAGNA&#160;(06N)</span>'
```

Comment: `print( title[0].text )` ?

Comment: or use `text()` in xpath - `title = doc.xpath('//*[@class="tytng"]/text()')` `print(title[0])`

Comment: `print( title[0].text )` that works fine :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ".text" if I understand your question correctly. For example:

```
title = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="tytng"]')
print(title.text)
```

Comment: `print(title.text)` gives me error:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: @Wojtas.Zet if you see word `"list"` in error then simply try with `[0]` - `title[0].text`

Comment: As furas said, try "find_elements_by_xpath", then title[index].text

Comment: What is `driver`? What is `find_element_by_xpath`? They don't exist in the question.